# Classification of Relative Clauses in English

Tags: syntax, english, linguistic-typology, relative-clauses

While reading the wikipedia article on relative clauses, I was puzzled somewhat by a description of a relative clause in English. It asserts that in the relative clause "that I saw yesterday", as in "the man that I saw yesterday went home", "that" is a complementizer rather than a pronoun, and that there is a gap left after "saw" where a pronoun would normally go.

My question is, why wouldn't you say that the relative clause is indicated by word order alone rather than gapping, "that" being moved from its usual position after the subject to the head of the phrase?

Here's a [link to the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Ways_of_forming_relative_clauses).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that's not the only way to look at the phenomenon, and it's not necessary
to believe that there are gaps like black holes left in sentences or anything like that.
But there's a point it makes.

There are two great families of pronouns, both descending from Proto-Indo-European roots:

- Demonstrative pronouns and their allies, descended from the [PIE root ****to-***](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628043014/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE534.html)
  In English these start with **TH**: *there, that, thither, thence, then, this, thus, though, the, they,* etc.
- Relative and interrogative pronouns and their allies, descended from the [PIE root ****kʷo-***](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628043014/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE258.html)
  In English these start with **WH**: *where, what, whither, whence, when, how, who, why, whether,* etc.

So if *that* is a relative pronoun, it's an odd one.

The thing is that *that* has been used for over 600 years to introduce tensed subordinate clauses.
And it still is used that way for two out of the three kinds of subordinate clauses in Modern English.
Tensed Noun clauses and Adjective clauses require or allow *that*, under varying rules:

- *Mary believes [**that** [the Earth is an oblate spheroid]].* [Complement (Noun) clause]
- *The man [**that** [Mary talked to]] didn't believe her*. [Relative (Adjective) clause]

Tensed Adverb clauses don't allow it any more, though they used to in Chaucer's day:

- *When he gets here, be sure to offer him a drink.*  (grammatical without *that*)
- **When that he gets here, be sure to offer him a drink.*  (ungrammatical with *that*)

But compare the first line of Chaucer:

- *Whan **that** aprill with his shoures soote the droghte of march hath perced to the roote*
  'When (*that) April with its showers sweet the drought of March has pierced to the root'

Now the kind of word that introduces a clause and doesn't have meaning as such 
is a **Complementizer**. Clearly this is the right term for the *that* in *that the Earth is an oblate spheroid*.
And it's obvious that it's the term for the way Chaucer used it, too.

So the question is, what is it when it heads a relative clause?

> If *that* is a relative pronoun, then there are a lot of questions that need answering:
>   Why is *that* so different from the other relative pronouns?
>   Why is *that* optional in restrictive relatives but forbidden in non-restrictive ones?
>   Why can *that* be used in any kind of clause, where WH relatives are specific to person, time, etc?
>   Why is it being used as a relative pronoun when it's already used as a complementizer?

On the other hand,

> If *that* is a complementizer in relative clauses, then these questions evaporate.
>   What appears then is a situation similar to complement clauses. 
>   *That* may be deleted in complements, just as it can be in relative clauses, and under the same conditions
>   -- whenever it's not needed to mark the subordinate clause as a subordinate clause, it's optional.
>
> This also solves all coreference problems, because complementizers are not referential.
>   Therefore if there is any coreference in the relative clause, it is coreference of the sort called "understood" (also, "deleted", "a gap", "zero", "Pro" (of two varieties), or some other term, depending usually on what year your syntax instructor got their PhD).

That's what they really mean, I think. There's quite a lot more one could say on the topic,
but I forbear.

Comment: Your answer overlooks one major fact that supports the analysis as a relative proform: there is in fact a sort "gap" present, e.g.

Comment: Your answer overlooks a major fact that supports the analysis as a relative proform: there is in fact a sort "gap" present, and it must remain empty, e.g. *the man that I met him..." If "that" were a straightforward complementizer, the object "him" should be possible. Observe the similarity to a true relative pronoun: "*the man who I met him...". In my view, the best analysis grants "that" an intermediate status between a relative pronoun and a complementizer.

Comment: Like I said above, "if there is any coreference in the relative clause, it is coreference of the sort called "understood" (also, "deleted", "a gap", "zero", "Pro" (of two varieties), or some other term)". Though to claim that a Gap is "present" is perhaps to get carried away on wings of metaphor.

Comment: I am no fan of empty elements in syntactic analysis, but to speak of them metaphorically is helpful. I think your response does not acknowledge the point I wanted to make. If "that" were always a real complementizer, the relative clause introduced by "that" would not be incomplete in a sense. To state that "that" in such cases is a complentizer and not a relative pronoun is to make the same mistake as stating that it is a relative pronoun and not a complementizer. The answer lies somewhere in between.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what "If _that_ were always a real complementizer, the relative clause introduced by _that_ would not be incomplete in a sense" could possibly mean, let alone what position it might argue for.

Comment: Observe: "(Fred said) that he saw it" vs. "*(Fred said) that he saw". The second sentence is incomplete and thus unacceptable; "saw" needs an object. If "that" is always a complementizer and never a relative pronoun, then the clauses it introduces should not allow the incompleteness. A relative pronoun is a relative pronoun because it completes the clause it introduces. That is exactly what "that" (as a relative pronoun) is doing. It is filling the "gap", completing the clause it introduces.

Comment: Further: If "that" were a straightforward complementizer and not a relative proform, the following relative clause (with "that" as the subject) is predicted to be bad: "(the man) that laughed". Relative clauses with the relative pronoun as the subject do not allow omission of the relative pronoun, e.g. "*The man __ laughed was annoying". In other words, these data are consistent with an analysis that views "that" as a subject relative pronoun. The alternative analysis that sees "that" as a complementizer can hardly address these cases.

Comment: For many people it probly **is** a proform, just as **whom** is now perceived as a high register term, and _by him and I_ is, likewise. There are many presuppositions buried in the argument that not everyone subscribes to. If you're rehearsing the imperative "you understood", I've already heard it. As I said (twice now) there's a missing reference in the relative clause, just as there is in _the man he saw_, just as there is in _Ever been to Anchorage?_, or _Bill wants to paint the bathroom_. There's lots of gapped, deleted, missing, uninserted, moved, NPs. They're not there. They're imaginal

Comment: Don't forget that 'that' and 'what' are at least semantically interchangeable in relative phrases: "The dog what bit me ran away."